# Read binary stdout data like screencap data from adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to read binary stdout from an adb shell command?  For example, all examples of how to use screencap include two steps:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/foo.png
adb pull /sdcard/foo.png
```

However, the service supports writing to stdout.  You can for instance, do the following:

```
adb shell "screencap -p > /sdcard/foo2.png"
adb pull /sdcard/foo2.png
```

And this works equally well.  But, what about reading the output across ADB?  What I want to do is the following:

```bash
adb shell screencap -p > foo3.png
```

And avoid the intermediate write to the SD card.  This generates something that *looks* like a PNG file (running `strings foo3.png` generates something with an IHDR, IEND, etc.) and is approximately the same size, but the file is corrupted as far as image readers are concerned.

I have also attempted to do this using ddmlib in java and the results are the same.  I would be happy to use any library necessary.  My goal is to reduce total time to get the capture.  On my device, using the two-command solution, it takes about 3 seconds to get the image.  Using ddmlib and capturing stdout takes less than 900ms, but it doesn't work!

Is it possible to do this?

EDIT: Here is the hexdump of two files.  The first one, screen.png came from stdout and is corrupted.  The second one, xscreen is from the two-command solution and works.  The images should be visually identical.

```
$ hexdump -C screen.png | head
00000000  89 50 4e 47 0d 0d 0a 1a  0d 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48  |.PNG..........IH|
00000010  44 52 00 00 02 d0 00 00  05 00 08 06 00 00 00 6e  |DR.............n|
00000020  ce 65 3d 00 00 00 04 73  42 49 54 08 08 08 08 7c  |.e=....sBIT....||
00000030  08 64 88 00 00 20 00 49  44 41 54 78 9c ec bd 79  |.d... .IDATx...y|
00000040  9c 1d 55 9d f7 ff 3e 55  75 f7 de b7 74 77 d2 d9  |..U...>Uu...tw..|
00000050  bb b3 27 10 48 42 16 c0  20 01 86 5d 14 04 11 dc  |..'.HB.. ..]....|
00000060  78 44 9d c7 d1 d1 11 78  70 7e 23 33 8e 1b 38 33  |xD.....xp~#3..83|
00000070  ea 2c 8c 8e 0d 0a 08 a8  23 2a 0e 10 82 ac c1 40  |.,......#*.....@|
00000080  12 02 81 24 64 ef ec 5b  ef fb 5d 6b 3b bf 3f ea  |...$d..[..]k;.?.|
00000090  de db dd 49 27 e9 ee 74  77 3a e3 79 bf 5e 37 e7  |...I'..tw:.y.^7.|

$ hexdump -C xscreen.png | head
00000000  89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a  00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52  |.PNG........IHDR|
00000010  00 00 02 d0 00 00 05 00  08 06 00 00 00 6e ce 65  |.............n.e|
00000020  3d 00 00 00 04 73 42 49  54 08 08 08 08 7c 08 64  |=....sBIT....|.d|
00000030  88 00 00 20 00 49 44 41  54 78 9c ec 9d 77 98 1c  |... .IDATx...w..|
00000040  c5 99 ff 3f d5 dd 93 37  27 69 57 5a e5 55 4e 08  |...?...7'iWZ.UN.|
00000050  24 a1 00 58 18 04 26 08  8c 01 83 31 38 c0 19 9f  |$..X..&....18...|
00000060  ef 7c c6 3e 1f 70 f8 7e  67 ee 71 e2 b0 ef ce f6  |.|.>.p.~g.q.....|
00000070  f9 ec 73 04 1b 1c 31 60  23 84 30 22 88 a0 40 10  |..s...1`#.0"..@.|
00000080  08 65 69 95 d3 4a 9b c3  c4 4e f5 fb a3 67 66 77  |.ei..J...N...gfw|
00000090  a5 95 b4 bb da a4 73 7d  9e 67 55 f3 ed 50 5d dd  |......s}.gU..P].|
```

Just at quick glance it seems like a couple of extra 0x0d (13) bytes get added.  Carriage return?? Does that ring any bells?  Is it mixing in some blank lines?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're combining the stdout of the program with the stdout of the command. I'm not set up to try this myself but have you looked at the file it creates in detail? If you open it up in a text editor, you might see a bad string that you can just remove.  And at the very least you can compare it with the correct version to see what the difference is.

Comment: Updated my question to add hexdumps of the two files.  I don't see any weird strings getting mixed in, but random bytes do seem to.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised at all if you're getting a couple extra cr's in there. You can probable run just "adb shell screencap -p" and see what the output is. Remember that you're not piping the output of screencap -p across adb but the the output of adb shell.

Comment: I used a hex editor to scrape out the two obvious wayward crs and tried to view the image again.  This time, it was recognized as a PNG by Preview (it was not before), but the image was blank.  Imagemagick still claims it is corrupted, so there may be more garbage in there.  Sigh.

Comment: like so : adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sorry to be posting an answer to an old question, but I just came across this problem myself and wanted to do it only through the shell. This worked well for me:

```bash
adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/^M$//' > screenshot.png
```

That `^M` is a char I got by pressing ctrl+v -> ctrl+m, just noticed it doesn't work when copy-pasting.

```bash
adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/\r$//' > screenshot.png
```

did the trick for me as well.

Comment: While above approach works great on Ubuntu, it didn't work for me on Mac OS X. This variation which uses Perl in place of sed does:
`adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png`

Comment: Anyone knows what the proper perl expression should be for windows - I have a team member who is unfortunate enough to be on a windows platform.

Comment: On windows I had to use `sed 's/\r$//' > screenshot.png` twice. Any idea why this is ?

Comment: @kanna probably because the `^` character has to be escaped in the windows shell.

Comment: For very very large files (e.g. dumping flash memory), this will not work (`sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX`).

Answer (score 103):

Unlike `adb shell` the `adb exec-out` command doesn't use `pty` which mangles the binary output. So you can do

```bash
adb exec-out screencap -p > test.png
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/5d9d434efadf1c535c7fea634d5306e18c68ef1f

Note that if you are using this technique for a command that produces output on STDERR, you should redirect it to `/dev/null`, otherwise `adb` will include STDERR in its STDOUT corrupting your output. For example, if you are trying to backup and compress a directory:

```bash
adb exec-out "tar -zcf - /system 2>/dev/null" > system.tar.gz
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why I get "error: closed" when I run this? I have ADB version 1.0.32

Comment: @Kristopher, 1.0.32 is ancient. please use more recent version

Comment: That seems like a very good idea if someone is running into the same problem nowadays. Of course this was one year and six days ago when 1.0.32 was the bleeding edge mate. The real answer was that I was on Windows doing my dev and even though the exec-out was supposed to ignore the line endings issue I kept getting it. The answer is obvious to me now though: just use frickin' Linux to dev Android and stop trying to fake it out on Windows.

Comment: Experimentally compared the shell+sed version and the exec-out command, and exec-out is faster by ~0.1s

Comment: I also get "error: closed" with this command. ADB version 1.0.39 on Win7. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ralph, `shell v2` needs to be supported by both `adb` on the PC host side and `adbd` on the device side. Your device is too old.

Comment: To make this even more interesting, on Windows, this works perfectly when running `adb` from cmd but mangles the PNG on powershell. CRLF to LF doesn't work on powershell either (using `adb shell`). I haven't tried to figure out where the extra noise it coming from because you can just switch to cmd.

Answer (score 16):

As noted, "adb shell" is performing a linefeed (0x0a) to carriage-return + linefeed (0x0d 0x0a) conversion.  This is being performed by the pseudo-tty line discipline.  As there is no "stty" command available to the shell, there is no easy way to mess with the terminal settings.

It's *possible* to do what you want with ddmlib.  You'd need to write code that executed commands on the device, captured the output, and sent it over the wire.  This is more or less what DDMS does for certain features.  This may be more trouble than its worth.

The `repair()` solution -- converting all CRLF to LF -- feels shaky but is actually reliable since the "corrupting" LF-to-CRLF conversion is deterministic.  I used to do the same thing to repair inadvertent ASCII-mode FTP transfers.

It's worth noting that the PNG file format is explicitly designed to catch exactly this (and related) problems.  The magic number begins with 0x89 to catch anything that strips high bits, followed by "PNG" so you can easily tell what's in the file, followed by CR LF to catch various ASCII line converters, then 0x1a to trap old MS-DOS programs that used Ctrl-Z as a special end-of-file marker, and then a lone LF.  By looking at the first few bytes of the file you can tell exactly what was done to it.

...which means that your `repair()` function can accept both "corrupted" and "pure" input, and reliably determine if it needs to do anything.

**Edit:** one additional note: it's possible for the device-side binary to configure the tty to avoid the conversion, using `cfmakeraw()`.  See the `prepareRawOutput()` function in the [screenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp) command in Android 5.0, which can send raw video from the live screen capture across the ADB shell connection.

Comment: Yes, the `repair()` solution is solid because of the determinism.  I optimized it a bit to reduce the number of write calls to the output stream and now there is no discernable increase in processing time.  Works great.  Thanks!

Comment: Re: "the 'corrupting' LF-to-CRLF conversion is deterministic": But is it reversible? If CRLF and LF are both converted to CRLF, then converting CRLF back to LF is *not* 100% reliable, since it will mess with cases where the original CRLF was correct.

Comment: In this case, CRLF becomes CRCRLF.  If CRLF were passed through unmodified then it wouldn't be reversible.

Comment: It's good to see the reason for that sed command explained here. Surprised to see that people weren't clamouring to know why the sed was necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 15):

The best solution is to use `adb exec-out` command like [@AjeetKhadke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447/1778421) suggested.

Let me illustrate the difference between `adb shell` and `adb exec-out` output:

```
~$ adb shell "echo -n '\x0a'" | xxd -g1
00000000: 0d 0a

~$ adb exec-out "echo -n '\x0a'" | xxd -g1
00000000: 0a
```

It works in Windows (I am using `hexdump` from [GNUWin32 Hextools](https://gigenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/hextools/1.0/hextools-1.0-bin.zip) for the demo) as well:

```
C:\>adb shell "echo -n '\x0a'" | hexdump
00000000: 0D 0A

C:\>adb exec-out "echo -n '\x0a'" | hexdump
00000000: 0A
```

The downside is that in order to be able to benefit from using the `adb exec-out` command both the device and host PC have to support `adb shell` V2 protocol.

It is rather trivial to take care of the PC side - just update the `platform-tools` package (which contains the `adb` binary) to the latest version. The version of `adbd` daemon on the device is linked to the version of Android. The `adb shell` V2 protocol has been introduced in Android 5.0 together with complete `adb` overhaul (going from `c` to `C++` code). But there were some regressions (aka bugs) so `adb exec-out` usefulness in Android 5.x was still limited. And finally there is no support for Android 4.x and older devices. Fortunately the share of those older devices still being used for development is dropping fast.

Comment: Thanks.  But I should have added that keeping the phone unrooted is a requirement, so I can't use busybox.  However, it does give me some ideas to try different utilities that do exist.

Comment: Most Android versions have had an unofficial place where one can put a small binary such as an encoding tool, though where it can go depends on the version.

Comment: My Android 4.3 device does not have busybox, nor uudecode.

Comment: These tests didn't work for me. I have been getting '\x0a' characters instead of binary LF.
In order to get correct LF I needed to add -e to echo command:
adb shell "echo -e -n '\x0a'
etc...

Comment: This doesn't word on Windows 10. I get 0d 0a for both! Oh, well, the answer is from 2012...

Answer (score 9):

After digging deeper into the hex dumps it became clear that every time the character 0x0A was emitted, the shell would emit 0x0D 0x0A.  I repaired the stream with the following code and now the binary data is correct.  Now, of course, the question is why is adb shell doing this?  But in any event, this fixes the problem.

```
static byte[] repair(byte[] encoded) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int i=0; i<encoded.length; i++) {
        if (encoded.length > i+1 && encoded[i] == 0x0d && encoded[i+1] == 0x0a) {
            baos.write(0x0a);
            i++;
        } else {
            baos.write(encoded[i]);
        }
    }
    try {
        baos.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }

    return baos.toByteArray();      
}
```

EDIT: It dawned on me why it is doing this.  It is converting LF to CR/LF like old-school DOS.  I wonder if there is a setting somewhere to turn that off?

Comment: It is possible by disabling it using `stty raw` prior to running the shell command as described by [Glenn Willen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13642296/427545).

Comment: I found my stream was being transformed from 0x0a => 0x0d 0x0d 0x0a.  Here is code that worked for me: `if ((i + 2) < encoded.length && encoded[i] == 0x0d &&
                    encoded[i+1] == 0x0d && encoded[i+2] == 0x0a) { ... `

Answer (score 8):

Yes, on Unix/Linux/Mac OS X, you can receive binary output of adb shell by prepend "stty -onlcr;" to your command (  **NO**~~ need to be a rooted android).

1.**Download "stty" executable file.**
   http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/
   For old android, use busybox-armv5l, Others use busybox-armv7l.
   rename file to "stty"

2.**Uploda file "stty" to android and set proper permission.**

```
adb push somelocaldir/stty /data/local/tmp/   
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp/stty
```

3.**Prepend "stty -onlcr;" to your command like this;**

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/stty -onlcr\; screencap -p  > somelocaldir/output.png
or:
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/stty -onlcr; screencap -p"  > somelocaldir/output.png
or (Only for Windows):
adb shell /data/local/tmp/stty -onlcr; screencap -p  > somelocaldir/output.png
```

Done!

But for Windows OS, by default, LF from android will be converted to CR CR LF.
Even you did above step, you still get CR LF.
This "seems" because local adb.exe use fwrite which cause CR be prepended.
I have no way about this except convert CR LF to LF manually on Windows OS.

Comment: This is fantastic. Many thanks! I'm writing some tools to backup an Android device over `adb` ([github.com/dlenski/tetherback](https://github.com/dlenski/tetherback)) and this really comes in handy. Much more straightforward than the `nc`-based approach that [others have suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34216105/20789).

Answer (score 5):

Here is solution that **works everywhere** (Linux and Windows included).

**You will need `netcat` utility, often named `nc`.**
If both `nc` and `busybox nc` fail on your device, you need fresh `busybox`. You can either use busybox installer from Play Market (root required), or use [solution by osexp2003](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141481/3710080) (download busybox from [official site](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/), put it into `/data/local/tmp/` on device and add execute permission).

**The idea is to use `netcat` as a primitive HTTP server.**
Well, not even a proper server in fact. It will just send its input as response to *any* TCP connection (be it HTTP request from browser, telnet connection or just `netcat`) and terminate.

**Run command you want to get output from like this:**

```bash
adb shell 'screencap -p | busybox nc -p 8080 -l >/dev/null'
```

In the above example, `screencap -p` takes a screenshot (PNG image) and pipes it to `netcat`.
`-l` tells `netcat` to act as a server (listen for connection), and `-p 8080` tells it to use TCP port 8080.
Omiting `>/dev/null` will simply print e.g. incoming HTTP GET request to your terminal.
The above example will wait for someone to connect, send screenshot and only then terminate.
Of course you can run it without `adb shell`, e.g. from terminal emulator on your device.

After running your command as above, **you can download its output from** your phone, by opening **`http://ip.of.your.phone:8080`** in browser or by any other means, for example using `netcat`:

```bash
busybox nc ip.of.your.phone:8080 >screenshot.png
```

**If you want to use USB cable for download**, you need to forward connection using ADB like this:

```bash
adb forward tcp:7080 tcp:8080
```

After that you can use `localhost:7080` instead of `ip.of.your.phone:8080`.
You can remove this forwarding with following command:

```bash
adb forward --remove tcp:7080
```

Comment: I didn't find any vanilla `nc` on my nexus 5x, but there was a `toybox` binary that had  `nc` compiled in, so I could use it as `toybox nc ...`. Thanks a lot for this hint.

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
adb shell "busybox stty raw; screencap -p "> foo3.png
```

BUT, [as @osexp2003 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20141481), **that does not work for Windows OS.**

Answer (score 3):

It is old question but may be this solution will be usefull for somebody.

For simply downloading any files from adb you can use:

`adb run-as your.package.name base64 -w 0 /path/to/your/file.db`

and then just read and decode base64 string in linux (as example):

`cat saved.base64.str|base64 -d`

Of course you can compress source data before encode it as base64.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the standard `dos2unix` command if its available.

(`apt-get install dos2unix` if you're on Debian/Ubuntu. There are probably builds for Windows, OS X, etc. out there somewhere if you google).

`dos2unix` converts CRLF to LF the same way as Eric Lange's `repair()` function.

```
adb shell screencap -p | dos2unix -f > screenshot.png
```

or, fix a corrupted file (in-place) :

```
dos2unix -f screenshot.png
```

You need the `-f` to force it to process binary files.

Comment: This works great for Windows where we have neither `sed` nor `perl` by default

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use base64 for this, so just encode it using:

```
base64 foo3.png>foo3.png.base64
```

and then on windows using some [base64 utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gbm64/) or maybe notepad++ to decrypt the file.

Or in linux / cygwin:

```
base64 -d foo3.png.base64>foo3.png
```

Comment: I didn't need screencap, but I did need tar. Here's what I did to copy all my pictures to my laptop: `time adb shell 'tar -C /sdcard/DCIM -cf - Camera | toybox base64' | base64 -D | tar -xf -`  Thanks for the base64 tip!

Answer (score 1):

try this guys:

```
adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the method to use python get image bytes using adb here, maybe this will be helpful to someone who encountered this problem. The code is as following:

```py
 pipe = subprocess.Popen("adb shell screencap -p",
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
 image_bytes = pipe.stdout.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
 gray_image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image_bytes, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to go in general is to use `adb exec-out`, as [Ajeet47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884052) and [Alex P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1778421) [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587203).

However, things get messy if there is anything in-between which creates a pseudo-tty.

I wondered why my tar files got corrupted even though I was using `adb exec-out`. The issue was using the `su` binary to spawn `tar` processes in my case. `su` seems to spawn a pseudo-tty and you can't turn that off, giving you the worst of both worlds.

Example:

```sh
% adb exec-out 'su -c '"'"'printf "\n"'"'" | xxd
00000000: 0d0a                                     ..
```

In such scenarios, you still need to tell the shell to not mangle line feeds with additional carriage return characters through means like `stty raw`:

```sh
% adb exec-out 'su -c '"'"'stty raw; printf "\n"'"'" | xxd                                                                  
00000000: 0a                                       .
```

However, as others pointed out, this might be fragile, especially for binary data. I haven't seen any issues when receiving `tar` output over `adb` when pairing `exec-out` with `stty raw` yet, but there certainly could be issues.

Hence, if you really want bit-for-bit equality, **check** if the generated data matches what you expect to catch surprising situations. This will not fix them, but at least alert you to them.

One way to do this is to checksum the original data while writing it out and checksum the received data on the host. A rather convoluted, but necessary, way to do this with POSIX-compatible systems and shells goes like that:

```sh
% adb exec-out 'su -c '"'"'stty raw && printf "\n" 2>/data/local/tmp/printf.stderr | { tee /dev/fd/3 | sha512sum -b - > /data/local/tmp/printf.sha512sum; } 3>&1'"'" | sha512sum -b - 
be688838ca8686e5c90689bf2ab585cef1137c999b48c70b92f67a5c34dc15697b5d11c982ed6d71be1e1e7f7b4e0733884aa97c3f7a339a8ed03577cf74be09 *-
% adb exec-out 'cat /data/local/tmp/printf.sha512sum'
be688838ca8686e5c90689bf2ab585cef1137c999b48c70b92f67a5c34dc15697b5d11c982ed6d71be1e1e7f7b4e0733884aa97c3f7a339a8ed03577cf74be09
```

**Do not** be tempted to use `bash`'s command line substitution feature (such as `cmd | tee >(sha512sum -b - > ...)`) since that will sadly drop a trailing newline and hence modify the original data.

Answer (score 0):

`nc` was the only way it worked for me. Used:

```bash
adb forward tcp:7080 tcp:8080 &&\    
adb shell 'tar -zcvf - /data/media | nc -p 8080 -l 1>/dev/null' &\    
sleep 1;\    
nc localhost 7080 > media.tar.gz &&\    
adb forward --remove tcp:7080
```

as root to create a hopefully proper backup for /data/media

Comment: This is actually a very smart idea! It's both clean & super fast.


Using `nc` in the subshell cleanly bypasses any shell/tty shenanigans: slow text processing, escape characters, and encoding issues. Instead, all the output goes directly through a local socket which solves all these issues and makes the transfer ludicrously fast. I compared both on my machine and it's twice faster than the exec-out + stty raw trick.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another solution for those apps, that **prevent adb from taking screenshots**.

You can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) for that. It works on Linux and Windows! Just run:

```
scrcpy
```

A windows with your device screen will open. You can now use **your local screenshot tool** (e.g. snipping tool on windows and screenshot on linux) to take a screenshot of the current screen!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29992594)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command and saves in the active directory

```bash
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen-shot.png
```

Answer (score -1):

This command worked for me on **Windows OS**:

```bash
adb exec-out screencap -p > test.png && dos2unix.exe -f test.png
```

But you want to use this:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/

Comment: `adb exec-out` works just fine in Windows without needing `dos2unix`. so your answer is redundant

Comment: Yes, but strangely just `exec-out` doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Try with `adb` from the latest `platform-tools` version. If it does not work - it means that your phone does not support the command properly.

Comment: it works for me,, but only when I use dos2unix twice, because I dont habe exec-out.

`adb shell screencap -p | dos2unix -f | dos2unix -f > Screencap.png`

Thx for the tipp with `dos2unix`

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way using Shell in OS

**`adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png`**