# ADB exec-out not working

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to capture my android emulator screen using ADB commands, but when I execute the command nothing happens, no error and no image, this is the command I'm running:

> adb exec-out screencap -p /sdcard/Pictures/test.png

I tried to use "adb shell....", but it is too slow for me.

Do I need something to run the "exec-out"? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you try quoting the subcommand? `adb "exec-out screencap -p /sdcard/Pictures/test.png"`, also, what is the return code of both versions? After running the command, `echo $?`

Comment: ADB Version 1.0.31, I just realized that running the command from command line directly, it lists all adb command, it kinda means "exec-out" does not exists, do I need to install something else?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  I'm having the exact same issue.  "exec-out" does exist, as 'adb exec-out pwd' prints 'error: closed' - NOT 'command not found' or something like that.

Comment: @jcovert, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13587203/1778421

Answer (score 2):

You need a one line only:

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > [path]
```

Example:

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > d:\screenshot.png
```

Comment: @Chris623 - 'exec-out' was added to adb as a command in a later version of Android.  I don't remember exactly, but Android < 5.0 definitely doesn't have exec-out.  So while this solution would work if I had 'exec-out', my question was different.

Answer (score 0):

"adb exec-out" gives binary output.

You can use below commands to save the screens

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screencap.png

adb pull /sdcard/screencap.png C:\\Users\\<username>\\Pictures\\screencap.png
```

More info :

[Read binary stdout data from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell)

Comment: As I said in the first post, I did use "adb shell screencap...", but it is too slow, it takes like ~500ms to create the .png file, it's too slow.

Comment: @Kyore Did you find a solution? I need help on this too.

Comment: Not really, exec-out never works and I couldn't find anything helpfull in the internet, so I gaveup for now hahaha

Comment: @Kyore if you are windows, try `adb exec-out "screencap -p | base64"` and then decode the output with base64,.

Comment: @lan Hu: I get the error: "base64: not found". And if I remove the quotes: "'base64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

`adb exec-out screencap` is a safe way to generate screenshot in bitmap format.

You can use pipe read that raw data. The first 4 bytes mark the little-endian integer for width. The next 4 bytes is the height. The next 4 bytes indicate the image format. Following bytes is raw data for the images like RGBA8888.

Note:
Do not use raw data from `adb shell screencap`. The shell will insert some line breaks so data could broke.

Ref:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/46f281edf5e78a51c5c1765460cddcf805e88d48/adb/daemon/framebuffer_service.cpp#L88-L91

Comment: It creates image file. But says invalid.

Comment: @Vivek MVK That's not standard image file. You need to read the raw buffer and build the image from the RGB data.

Comment: `adb shell screencap` line break can be removed using sed `'s|\r\r$||'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that `adb exec-out screencap` is too slow or problematic for your case you can try [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/take-screenshot) which would be much faster.

You can even use `curl` or any other HTTP client to take the screenshot like this

```
curl -sf -H 'accept: image/png' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET 'http://localhost:9987/v2/uiDevice/screenshot' > img.png
```

See the complete example at [take-screenshot](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/take-screenshot).