# How to show ADB screenshot directly in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, adb

I want to display screenshot from adb screencap directly in python without generate a file, is there any way to do this?

I have tried opencv, here is my code:

```
command = r"adb shell screencap -p"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.stdout.read(30000000)
img = cv2.imdecode(out,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
if img is not None:
    cv2.imshow("",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("")
```

but I got this error on "imdecode" line:

```
TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I am using python3.6 and OpenCV3.4, on Windows 7. ADB v1.0.36, Android version is 8.0

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: update your `adb` and read https://stackoverflow.com/q/13578416/1778421

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to GPPK, now it's working:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("adb shell screencap -p",
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
image_bytes = pipe.stdout.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image_bytes, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("")
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as the answer for future viewers!

Comment: My image_bytes can not transform back to valid numpy arry using `fromstring`

Comment: Should use context manager to close Popen properly: `with subprocess.Popen(....) as proc: bytes = proc.stdout.read()`

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment so I will post it here instead.

The accepted answer is not working on Windows (Not sure if it's OS related).

After looking into a png file myself, I figured that it's not necessary to replace '\r\n', so deleting the following line from that solution should work.

```
image_bytes = pipe.stdout.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
```

P.S. You can check a png file yourself by using the following code:

```
with open("screenshot.png", 'rb') as f:
     data = f.read()

print(data)
```

The result should be something like: b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00........

Comment: I don't see the code to replace in the question. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use numpy.frombuffer() to create a uint8 array from the string:

```
command = r"adb shell screencap -p"
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.stdout.read(30000000)
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(out, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  
if img is not None:
    cv2.imshow("",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("")
```

**This is untested

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for you, another solution:

```
command = "adb shell \"screencap -p | busybox base64\""
pcommand = os.popen(command)
png_screenshot_data = pcommand.read()
png_screenshot_data = base64.b64decode(png_screenshot_data)
pcommand.close()
images = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(png_screenshot_data, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("",images)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("")
```

for me, imdecode return None with this:

```
image_bytes = pipe.stdout.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image_bytes, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```