# ADB: pipe new created file direct to pc

Tags: android, adb

I have the following usecase:
On my Android will create a huge file. This file can be bigger as the free space on the phone. Now I think for a way to send this file direct to the pc instead of storing it on the phone.

Is there a possibility to pipe the file direct? It is a huge text file. The I can trigger the creation.

- Anything like create on the phone(root rights exist) a pipe with the filename
- send it over ADB to the pc
- store the content.

Anyone knows a way to do it?

Thanks Björn

Comment: There is windows share, samba protocol, which you can use.

Comment: `send it over ADB to the pc` ?

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell

Answer (score 0):

I found a option to output the data on the screen and than I can use "adb shell command > file_on_local_pc.txt"

This is more simple as expected. Thanks

Comment: If the file to be piped contains non-ascii characters just piping from `adb shell` will fail as it modifies certain characters. Therefore `adb exec-out` is the safe variant when piping data via adb.