# How to take screenshot in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, screenshot

From Android 4.0, it supports volumn down+power key to take screenshot and saved in gallery. But how to do this in android emulator.

I know in eclipse, there is a 'take screenshot' button, but this is not what I want. I need it in the emulator and saved in emulator.

Comment: I don't think that there is an other way to do it. (At least I did not come off an other way.)

Comment: Do you want to take it Programmatically?

Comment: No... what i am doing is, add an app option to process the screenshot for the share intent after taking screenshot. I want to test it in emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take emulator screenshots using Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screenshots-using-eclipse)

Comment: This works fine if you are using Android Studio 2.0 or above:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35454101/6287190

Answer (score 76):

As seen in this post: [Screenshot of the Nexus One from adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807070/screenshot-of-the-nexus-one-from-adb), you can also take a screenshot using adb:

```
 adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
 adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.png
```

Comment: nice. I also found a one liner:   adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png

Comment: In the emulator, the resulting png is 0 bytes.. Any other way around this?

Comment: Note that this won't work if you enable the option "Use Host GPU". The screenshot will be an empty png (0 byte). Turn of "Use Host GPU" and it will work OK, although the emulator will be terribly slow (and might not even start with large screen sizes).

Comment: Had to work a bit to find a writable directory, using some adb shell ls -l did help there - then this worked great.

Comment: Found another one liner workaround [here](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/grab-android-screenshot-to-computer-via.html)

Comment: a longer 'oneliner' for saving a timestamped screenshot to the current dir: `fname="screenshot-`date +%Y-%m-%d-_%H_%M_%S`.png" && adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p "/sdcard/$fname" && adb pull "/sdcard/$fname" .` (make sure to include the final dot)

Answer (score 75):

### just click in photo icon for  take screenshot in android emulator

[image]

Comment: Does not work.  Android Emulator does not look anything like that and does not have that button.

Comment: @birigy OP specified "I need it in the emulator and saved in emulator" how do you save the image in the emulator with this method?

Answer (score 19):

In new emulator you can do it by pushing camera icon. By default it saved in desktop.

[image]

Comment: This fails to answer the original request: "I need it in the emulator and saved in emulator." This solution will save the screenshot to your desktop, not the emulator.

Answer (score 7):

Window > Show View > Other. In the newly opened dialog box, under Android category, select Devices.

Now on the Devices panel, Click the button as shown in the Image and your screenshot is ready.

Comment: As shown in what image? I found the icon, but it's not clear from the answer where it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ddms which has option to take screen shot. 
On DDMS -> Select Device -> Select Screen Capture

**Edit**
AFIK its not possible but this scenario will solely depend emulator image. Device hotkey might work on some OS images. Try same key combination from emulator [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

If your emulator uses factory or same images then it should be possible. You can download factory images for your emulator. see available nexus images from this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) also it is possible to download images from manufacturer site.

Alternatively you can take screen shot following way,

```
View content = findViewById(R.id.myView);
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
```

And later save this anywhere you like. This is not optimal solution and it will only print what you have inside your view.

Comment: Specifically said that this was not a solution.

Comment: I don't think this works. I want to take screenshot inside the emulator, so that I can share to other app directly.

Answer (score 5):

Long Press on Power button from the left side menu. then you will have the option for the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: This is the appropriate solution on Android versions that support it. Older versions may only give you "Power Off" and "Restart" options.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a screenshot if you open the Android view "devices" (under Window --> Show View --> Other... --> Android --> Devices). Click on the device or emulator you want to take a screen shot of, then click the "Screen Capture" button (it looks like a little picture, and it should be next to a stop sign button). Occasionally the device won't immediately load the picture; sometimes you have to close/reopen the screen capture window.

This is equivalent to taking a picture via DDMS, but you can do it in Eclipse instead of opening another application.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash -f
while : ; do

echo "press the number of the screenshot to capture";

read i

adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png "${i}.png"

done
```

---

```
ctrl-c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply press the shortcut key i.e. ctlr + S to take screenshot in the emulator.

Also there is a button given on the emulator to take the screenshot.

Simply press
[this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31GFB.png) button and you'll have a screenshot of the emulator.

Hope that it helped you.

Comment: This doesn't work on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your emulator then press:

> ctrl + s

to save your screenshot.

hope its work.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac.