# Taking screenshot on Emulator from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I know this probably might be the silliest question but still, I don't know how to take a screenshot of Emulator via Android Studio. I recently switched from Eclipse to Android Studio and I could not find it anywhere, I tried to search on web too but no help.

Answer (score 374):

Starting with Android Studio 2.0 you can do it with the new emulator:

[image: New Android Emulator from Android Studio 2.0]

Just click 3 "Take Screenshot". Standard location is the desktop.

Or

1. Select "More"
2. Under "Settings", specify the location for your screenshot
3. Take your screenshot

**UPDATE 22/07/2020**

If you use the emulator inside Android Studio which is possible since Android Studio 4.1 click here to save the screenshot in your standard location:

[image]

Comment: @Nino Handler I do just this, but no image appears on my desktop (and if I change the location, still no luck), so as a result I can't take screenshots using the emulator. Could you give some tips to get it sorted out?

Comment: @agiro I would recommend to use Fidel Eduardo López's or HenBoy331's answer which should also work.

Comment: It makes screenshots with wrong colors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462962/why-does-android-studio-emulator-show-different-colors-than-on-the-screenshots-t

Comment: For me it started working when I changed the default Desktop location to my Pictures library. Before all looked fine, but it didn't save the screenshot

Comment: Where is the photo saved, in the standalone emulator?

Comment: After the camera icon is clicked the screenshot will appear and you'll see at its bottom a button to save it. Once you click save your file explorer will appear allowing you to choose the location.

Answer (score 94):

Click on the **Monitor (DDMS Included)** button on the toolbar -- it looks like the Android bugdroid:

[image: IDE window showing Monitor button]

That will bring up the DDMS window. Select the emulator instance from the **Devices** tab on the left, and click on the camera button in the toolbar above it, next to the stop sign icon:

[image: Monitor window]

Note that if your emulator is running Android 4.4 or I think 4.3, then screen capture functionality is broken -- you'll have to use a physical device to get screenshots on those OS versions. It works okay for Android prior to 4.3. That bug is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62284

Comment: You can also launch DDMS from Terminal. Just enter 'ddms' to launch it

Comment: Thanks for the info on the bug, that is what was keeping me from getting a screenshot.

Answer (score 74):

You can capture a screenshot from Android Studio as shown in the image below.
[image: You can take capture from Android Studio]

Comment: Just a note, this icon is available when the, "Android Monitor", tab is selected.

Answer (score 71):

To take a screenshot of your app:

1. Start your app as described in Run your App in Debug Mode.
2. Click **Android** [image: 6:Android button] to open the Android DDMS tool window.
3. Click **Screen Capture** [image: Camera button] on the left side of the Android DDMS tool window.
4. Optional: To add a device frame around your screenshot, enable the Frame screenshot option.
5. Click **Save**.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I just get a dialog with a progressbar that says 'Obtaining screenshot from device...' but it never completes.

Comment: would give extra bonus for screen capure with device frame :)

Answer (score 36):

Keeping the emulator on top of all other task on the desktop and pressing "**Ctrl + S**", also captures the screen shot and it is saved on default(if, not edited) path(i.e. C:\Users\username\Desktop).

Or

you can just click on the "Camera" icon highlighted in "green", which we have with the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Look in [...] -> Settings to find out where the "Screenshot save location" is for this device.

Answer (score 34):

Please use `ctrl`+`s` on Windows or `⌘s` on Mac (while the emulator is focused). Your `Desktop` should be the default save location.

Answer (score 32):

Besides using Android Studio, you can also take a screenshot with adb which is faster.

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

Shorter one line alternative in Unix/OSX

```
adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png
```

Original blog post:
[Grab Android screenshot to computer via ADB](http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/grab-android-screenshot-to-computer-via.html)

Answer (score 15):

Long Press on Power button, then you will have the option for the screenshot.
[image: Power Button Emulator]

[image: Option for screenshot in emulator]

Comment: doesn't work on Android 7, 11

Answer (score 5):

1. In Android Studio, select **View** > **Tool** Windows > **Logcat** to open Logcat.
2. Select the device and a process from the drop-down at the top of the window.
3. Click Screen Capture  on the left side of the window.

For more info Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot)

Answer (score 3):

1.First run your Application
2.Go to Tool-->Android-->Android Device Monitor
[image: Check image for more detail]

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to

> Emulator settings > Settings > General > Screenshot save location >
> '***your file path***'

then select your desire location to save your screenshot.

2. After setup your emulator settings then press:

> ctrl + s

to save your screenshot.

hope its work.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Camera icon that is there on the right to emulator in action icons list. This is available on latest studio, though I am not sure from which version.

[image]

Comment: Andrev already posted similar answer, so this is a duplicated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I think I some how missed seeing that answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy with Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1

Run your emulator and at the top you will have a set of Icons select the Camera Icon which will trigger a screenshot and a preview with various options to modify or edit your picture before saving it.

[image: Initial First Image]

This is the new Window you get after clicking the Camera Icon which has an option to change the location of where to save the screenshot.

[image: Window for screenshot preview]

Answer (score 0):

Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2.
To start the standalone Device Monitor application in Android Studio 3.1 and lower you can run android-sdk/tools/monitor.bat

Answer (score 0):

On windows:
I found that my firewall blocks write access to screenshot. A workaround is to take a snapshot and find it in:
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME.android\avd\YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME.avd\snapshots\snap_SNAPSHOT_TIME