# How can I project my Android phone screen to my computer monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

For the sake of a class, I want to give an Android app development demo which I hope I can project whatever displayed on the device to my computer (so that I can further project in front of the class). I was thinking whether ADB has already supported this feature, though I didn't find a desired command in Android Development website yet ([link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html)). But I'm aware the following two commands:

- screencap
- screenrecord (available on API 19 onward)

For the first `screencap` command, I can write a bash script and put a while loop to loop over screencap and pull the image to my computer, this answer pretty much did what I just described ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701428/4713342)). However, since my target device is Nexus 5 whose screen resolution is 1920x1080, it takes almost 2 seconds to fetch a frame. Is there a way to specify the resolution size of output images?

The second choice is `screenrecord` command. However, it has to be saved locally (i.e., on the phone) and then pull to the computer to play. Though I'm sure making a streaming record, pulling out to the computer, and playing clips can be pipelined, it has to be imposed a delay of several seconds. What is a good practice to streaming the device display on the computer?

I'm okay with other solutions, in fact, I've also explored AndroidStudio, but it seems streaming is not supported.

Comment: Vysor may be what you are looking for: http://www.vysor.io/

Comment: use Vysor, generally use that, Install the Android app from Google play, and install the desktop app from Google chrome store

Comment: vysor would be a great choice.

Comment: The Android Enthusiasts site has several approaches to this problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the app called AirDroid then you can do remote viewing of your Android device if it's supported (Or definitely if it's rooted). I've found that it works pretty well, however when not rooted you are required to have a USB connection to your phone.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en