# How to take screenshot on emulator and save it on computers hardisk using android studio?

Tags: android

I wanted to save my screenshot on the computers hard disk memory for another use. The screenshot is captured successfully but stored in internal memory of emulator. So how can I solve my problem? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: please do some research on your own before asking here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking screenshot on Emulator from Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983351/taking-screenshot-on-emulator-from-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a nice option in Android Studio:

[Take a screenshot](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot.html)