# Android Emulator Screenshots Stopped Working

Tags: android, screenshot

I am using the Android emulator that came with the Android Studio SDK. I have several set up and they all do the same thing.

I am on MacOS Catalina latest version.

The first time I did a screenshot today it worked fine. It saved the shot on my desktop.

I then went to take a second shot and in the emulator it shows it took it, but no file showed up in Desktop.

I took several more and they just don't show up. I used Finder to search for the name that is showing in the emulator tool and they are not found anywhere on my hard drive.

I can delete them, take more shots and they show up with a preview in the emulator tool, but I can't find them anywhere on my hard drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question ?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983351/taking-screenshot-on-emulator-from-android-studio)

Comment: That does not. It worked the first time, but after that no screenshots appear anyway. I rebooted the computer and everything.