# which commands line are used to take a screenshot on android device (except screencap)

Tags: screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of my rooted samsung device using command line. 
I have a constraint of time, I shouldn't exceed 2 s.
So my question is how can i take a screenshot using command line.

Comment: This answer is good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31401447/211292

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screenshot of the Nexus One from adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807070/screenshot-of-the-nexus-one-from-adb)

Answer (score 6):

The following commands can be used to take a screenshot.

```
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.png
```

[Source](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/08/capture-screenshot-record-screen-using-adb.html)

---

**Update:** After some research I've noticed a similar question that has an answer that might help you:

> If the slow part is raw to png conversion (`time adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/x.png` is considerably slower than `time adb shell screencap /sdcard/nonpng.raw`, as I have it in games)
>
> This shell script by max_plenert is a better example:
>
> ```
> adb shell screencap /sdcard/mytmp/rock.raw
> adb pull /sdcard/mytmp/rock.raw
> adb shell rm /sdcard/mytmp/rock.raw
>
> // remove the header
> tail -c +13 rock.raw > rock.rgba
>
> // extract width height and pixelformat:
> hexdump -e '/4 "%d"' -s 0 -n 4 rock.raw
> hexdump -e '/4 "%d"' -s 4 -n 4 rock.raw
> hexdump -e '/4 "%d"' -s 8 -n 4 rock.raw
>
> convert -size 480x800 -depth 8 rock.rgba rock.png
> ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098784/4579864)

Comment: it takes 10 s , I test it now

Comment: What size is the screenshot?

Comment: size of my phone: 1080x1920, using this command I can't change the size of the screenshot?

Comment: I meant the size of the file. And what time are you measuring, the time it takes to pull or the time to actually take it?

Comment: the size of the file is 1,96 Mo , i'm measuring the time to take the screenshot

Comment: I updated the answer. I suggest checking out the source as well.

Comment: the command convert is unkown on my phone , I should do everything on phone not on pc, even the screenshot I can keep it on phone

Comment: I test the command ffmpeg, on my pc it gives a screenshot with wrong colors , on my phone it doesn't work at all

Comment: where is the file that I should add to my phone, so that it can know the command ffmpeg, I think it's a sh file